# Repeating Background Function iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, location

I am using the Google Place Library for iOS to see what business the user is currently at. I need this to run indefinitely, ideally do one call every 5 minutes or so even when the app is suspended.

I have started background location updates which gives me a reliable way to make the Library call, however trying to defer the location updates never works and always returns "Domain=KCLErrorDomain Code=11" error from the didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError function. I am trying to defer the update to once every 5 minutes to conserve battery, but the didUpdateLocations function is still called at 1hz intervals.

I actually do not even need to use location services because the Library handles it all, but I can't seem to find any reliable way to have a function called every x minutes in the background.

My question is, is there anyway to have a function called every 5 minutes from the background on iOS without using the location services or push notifications? Or if not, how can I get the location services to respect the deferred updates?

Testing on iPhone 6 10.3

Comment: Code 11 is `kCLErrorDeferredFailed`. You can get that if the physical device you're testing this on doesn't have GPS hardware.

Comment: The phone has GPS and returns coordinates every location tick. Like I said iPhone 6

Comment: What does [`deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423830-deferredlocationupdatesavailable) return?

Comment: Always returns false. I found a few stack overflow questions and a apple dev forum saying there broken: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62863

Comment: I see the same on iPhone 7+ running iOS 11.0.1.

Comment: So frustrating. Thanks for testing though.